# nordVPN change my firewall settings

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm concerning about nordVPN and firewall settings. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS linux. When I activate nordVPN connection nordVPN package disable my ufw firewall and set its own settings.
I'm not sure if it doesn't open my system to some attacks.

I'm not sure what mean following in my Chain INPUT (policy DROP):

iptables -L output:

```
Chain     INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost/8          anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

(I change 10.0.0.0/24 from original value, just because not sure what it mean. IP address of vpn server - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

so

```
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

- is that mean that my computer is open to all connections (attacks) from local network? Is that ok?

```
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost/8          anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere       ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

- I'm not sure what mean these two lines.

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

- Does this mean that I'm open from anywere?

Why nordVPN set policy of forward chain to accept?

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
```

Should I enable ufw after establishing vpn connection? This will change forward policy to DROP.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want NordVPN to mess with your firewall settings, disable its "killswitch" feature:

`nordvpn set killswitch off`

I'm not going into detail on the iptables rules, but they are probably fine.

More info [here](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm)